# Can't open multiple programs at once

Tags: python

I'm working on a piece of code in Python 3 that acts as an interface for various dead by daylight cheats. I'm using a very basic setup, just input() and os.system() to find and open specific files. It works fine, but there's one small issue.

The interface uses cmd prompt, and I have it set up so that entering numbers 1-4 will open programs and executables used to modify the game. However, some of the programs are required to stay open while others run. For example, the BVHR Session Grabber must be running along with the SaveInjector Interface, because the SaveInjector needs to receive a certain code from the Grabber.

There's a problem here, the code is set up in such a way that you can only run one file at a time. I'm not sure what exactly causes this, but I'll try to explain what happens. When entering the number 1, for example, into the cmd prompt window, it opens the BHVR Session Grabber (as intended). After that, the interface becomes unusable until I close the BHVR Session Grabber. I can't type anything into it while it's active, so I can't open multiple programs at once.

Not entirely sure if this is intended or not, but I'm hoping it's avoidable. If anyone has any knowledge on the issue let me know how to find a way around this in the comments please.

```
import os.path
def interface():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print("""
    \n\nSelect a cheat below:
    \n
    \n1: BHVR Session Grabber
    \n2: SaveInjector Interface
    \n3: Rank / Shards Editor
    \n4: Exit\n
    """)

def checker():
    interface()
    lst = ['1','2','3','4']
    good_input = input(">")

    global user_input
    user_input = None
    while not user_input:
        if good_input in lst: 
            user_input = good_input
        else:
            print("Enter a valid integer.")
            good_input = input(">")
        
checker()
cwd = os.getcwd()

def selection():
    if user_input == '1':
        f = (os.path.join(cwd, 'Programs', 'BHVRSession', 'CookieFinder.exe'));
        os.system(f)
        checker()
        selection()
        
    elif user_input == '2':
        os.system('cmd /k "cd Programs & cd Injector & SI.exe & cd.. & cd.. & Ultimate.py"')
        
    elif user_input == '3':
        f = (os.path.join(cwd, 'Programs', 'RankShards', 'Sender.exe'));
        os.system(f)
        checker()
        selection()
        
    elif user_input == '4':
        os.system('cmd /k "taskkill/im py.exe"')

selection()
```

Comment: Indeed, `os.system()` runs a program and blocks until it has finished running. Maybe look at the `subprocess` module instead; but keeping an interactive process running and communicating with it intermittently is probably better done with a higher-level library like `pexpect`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `os.system()` is blocking. This means that it will only return and continue executing your Python code after the program it runs finishes. Instead, you should look at the `subprocess` package to learn how to fork a new process that can run in parallel with your Python program.

Comment: @mimky Specifically, [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess%20popen#subprocess.Popen) is what you should use.